# Passing array values to struct constructor

Tags: c++, struct, lambda, constructor

Is it possible to pass values from array to struct constructor in better way then:

```
struct A {
std::string a;
std::string b;
};

std::string array[2] = {"looks", "bad"};
A a = {array[0], array[1]};
```

Making it that way looks bad, isn't readable and small changes cause a lot of problems. I don't mind using something else then simple array, but I cannot think of resolution to that problem. I was thinking about using lambda that would return every value from array, but I'm currently learning C++ and don't know if it's even possible and if it's how to code that.

Comment: [Compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/376c0bf172f409d0)

Comment: Ye, I know, but my question is that can be achieved in better way, because sometimes u have bigger structures and arrays.

Comment: Why not pass it in directly and skip the array?

Comment: What is the underlying and actual problem you need to solve with this code? Please always include a description of it in your questions. Or ask directly about that problem, and present your current solution as an attempt while describing why you think it's not good enough.

Comment: My goal was to pass value from array to struct constructor. In my project I am reading data from .txt file to array then I am passing that data to constructor, but ```={arr[1], arr[2], ..., arr[12]}``` isnt very readable, so I was looking for better solution

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to deal with a pre-existing array then a "better" way is to write a constructor or `A` that accepts an array, like this:

```cpp
struct A {
A(const std::vector<std::string>& args) : a(args[0]), b(args[1]) { };
A(const std::string* args) : a(args[0]), b(args[1]) { };
std::string a;
std::string b;
};
```

Where the first version is preferable since passing `std::vector` means it includes length information that the second form really doesn't include.

Comment: I was thinking about creating custom constructor and I think I am forced to do it that way, because I think it's not possible to loop through array in constructor